# Brief Question About a Particular Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am reading a text book and in it, a sequence is described as follows:

"Let $x_1=1$, and for each $n\in N$ define

$x_{n+1} = (1/2)x_n + 1$"

Then he writes:

"Using this rule, we can compute $x_2 = (1/2)(1)+1 = (3/2)$,   $x_3 = 7/4$"

That's where I'm confused... if the value input for $x_n$ to find $x_2$ by the original equation is $(1)$... Shouldn't the input to find $x_3$ be $(2)$, thus $x_3 = (2)$?

How did he arrive at (7/4) for $x_3$? What rule is being followed here?

Thanks.

Comment: $(1/2)(3/2)+1=(3/4)+1=7/4$.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I understood what you sent already, solving for 7/4. But I don't understand how he goes from imputing (1) for the second term in the sequence, and (3/2) for the third term in the sequence.

Comment: @amarsilio "*the value input for $x_n$ to find $x_2$ by the original equation is $(1)$*" $\;-\;$ That's just because $x_1$ happens to be $1$. The rule says $x_2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot x_1 + 1 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 +1 = \frac{3}{2}$, then $x_3 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot x_2 + 1 = \dots$

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now. I was imputing the subscript itself. Whoops.